# PHP Abstraction Layer - Get class from name

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm writing a simple database abstraction layer in PHP. I'm currently working on query builders, classes that build the SQL "code".

Are there any better ways for doing something like this?

```
if($dbengine == "MySQL")
{
    MySQLQueryBuilder::buildInsert($table, $data);
}
else if($dbengine == "PgSQL")
{
    PgSQLQueryBuilder::buildInsert($table, $data);
}
// And so on...
```

I'm thinking something like:

```
$querybuilder = get_class_from_name($dbengine . "QueryBuilder");
$querybuilder::buildInsert($table, $data);
```

Any ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: This sounds like a perfect match for the venerable strategy pattern.

Comment: You should have an instance `$engine` of either `MySQLQueryBuilder` or `PgSQLQueryBuilder`. Both classes should implement an interface `SQLQueryBuilder` that specifies a public method `buildInsert($table, $data)`. That way, you'd be able to simply call `$engine->buildInsert($table, $data);`. That's the proper object-oriented way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this if you want it to be static:

```
$statement = call_user_func(array($dbengine . 'QueryBuilder', 'buildInsert'), $table, $data);
```

But I would agree with Niko comment, having instance of builder would look much nicer.

**Update:**

With the way as Niko suggested, you could just do:

```
$className = $dbengine . 'QueryBuilder';
$builder = new $className();
$statement = $builder->buildInsert($table, $data);
```

So no `if`s required at all, code looks shorter and cleaner...

Comment: It doesn't have to be static. As you said, non-static looks nicer. I'm fiddling around with it and i'll see what i can come up with.